# JavaScript RegExp Optional Capture Group

Tags: javascript, regex

Given these two strings:

```
let query = "select color, year from car where color = blue and year = 2002";
```

or

```
let query = "select color, year from car";
```

I created the following `RegExp` with `String.prototype.match` to extract the columns, the table name and the where clause (optional)

```
var results = query.match(/select (.*) from (.*) where (.*)/);
```

For the first query, the result is what I was expecting:

```
[ 
  'select color, year from car where color = blue and year = 2002',
  'color, year',
  'car',
  'color = blue and year = 2002',
  index: 0,
  input: 'select color, year from car where color = blue and year = 2002' 
]
```

For the second query, I got a null, and if I try to change the RegExp to consider the where clause optional, it changes the capture groups and also does not work:

```
var results = query.match(/select (.*) from (.*)( where (.*))?/);
```

Any idea about how to use capture groups, where one of those are optional, in this situation? I have other strategies to implement that but I really would like to keep using the capture groups.

Thanks

Comment: just use "non remembering" grouping parens:  `query.match(/select (.*) from (.*)(?:where (.*))?/)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to surround the optional WHERE clause with a non-capturing group and make that optional. I've also change it slightly because you probably don't want to match *any* character `.`. You can always change that back.

```
var regex = /select\s+([\w ,]+)\s+from\s+(\w+)(?:\s+where([\w =]+))?/gi;
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gpQ1DP/1)

I would be remiss though if I didn't mention that processing code with regexes is a **terrible** idea. You can always use an SQL parser.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really!